# IE 8/10 compatibility issue: My aside is dropping below my main, when it should be side-by-side

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

IE 8/10 CSS compatibility issue: My 'aside' is dropping below my 'main', when it should be side-by-side. Works fine on everything else.
http://rgvhondadealers.com/comparisons/

It seems like the issue may lie in the float, however, when you go to the specials page which is in the same format, the issue is no longer there.
http://rgvhondadealers.com/specials/

Any help at all will be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can't account for your issues in IE10, however your IE8 issues may be the fact that you are using width calc() to determine the width of your "main" tag. There isn't any support in IE8 for width calc(). See http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: Using a backup method:
width: 500px; /* older browsers */;
width: calc( 100% - 400px );

Comment: Yes, my apologies, just spotted that. Still looking.